# Why might my web site not work in IE9 on an SOE (locked down) PC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

My web site, http://postrace.com.au, works fine for me under IE9 on Windows 7. However I have users within government/corporate business units reporting that the site content (ie the images under Gallery) do not show. I know that they have IE9 and are using Windows 7. Since I do not have access to their computers, I am at a loss to guess what the issue could be. Could someone here view the site and the page source and give me their best guess at what could be stopping the page from completely rendering?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**I just used IE10 based with browser+doc mode IE9, your site looks good enough.**

Are you using a native IE9 or using browser+document mode to change?

Ask them to reset their browser settings, I have a feeling that their IE is running in "**[Quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html)**" , which cause the images to be blank and messes up the page layout.  You must confirm with them what they are using. Ask them to try another machine.

Plus, never trust the users, they tend to ignore some facts and they might be using netescape on win95!! Once a user reported an error, it turned out that his browser plug in was injecting some JS code into the html doc, and his internet was very slow, so his plugin couldn't load correctly and caused the javascript to trigger an error.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I confirmed both users are using native IE9 on Windows 7, by sending them to http://www.whatismybrowser.com.

Comment: All of you are running IE9 and win7, yet they are not showing the site correctly! means something must be different. First thing i would check is the browser mode, maybe by mistake they have changed it, or one plugin is screwing with their IE settings. Check this -> (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2823575)  and this -> (http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html). 
Other than than, all what I can do is wishing you good luck.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. After a bit of experimentation (yet to be confirmed by the users) I am leaning towards a group policy restriction of "Active Scripting" in IE security settings being set as disabled. Thanks for your help.